# Drill can't penetrate wall fully

Tags: drywall, walls, drill, curtain-rail

I'm currently attempting to install a curtain rail in my bedroom, but my drill is getting stuck at 2cm deep.

There were previous holes there, but they were too big so I filled them and tried drilling slightly above and below them, they were at least 3.5cm deep.

Im in the UK and this is on the ground floor above a window.

Previous holes marked in red
[image: my two attempts and the previous holes marked red]

This seems to be rotated 90 anticlockwise , but it's in the top corner of the room
[image: some more context as to where they are]

Comment: What type of drill are you using? A masonry drill probably will have issues, but a HSS drill should be fine. Spanning the window opening on a lot of UK houses is a steel lintel - you're probably bouncing off that.

Comment: @PeteCon I tried HSS, my bit got discoloured and I smell burning. I then tried a more powerful hammer drill, turns out it was just very hard brick

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Would you add this as an answer, so future searchers can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a cordless hammer drill which wasn't powerful enough to get through the material behind the plasterboard. 
I managed when I used a more powerful (1KW) drill.